# Getting dihedrals of a polyhedron object

Tags: polyhedra

I am generating a refined icosahedron as follows:

```
Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"]
Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 3]
```

The output is:

[image]

I can also exract the face coordinates as

```
faces = Cases[Normal@Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 3], _Polygon, Infinity];
f = faces // N;
```

My question is, how to get all the dihedral angle values between all neighboring faces? I'm using Mathematica 11.3.0.0 and neither the functions `DihedralAngle` nor `PolyhedronAngle` seem to be implemented.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid that one has to resort to extracting the geometry. Here is an example:

```
Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"]
hedron = Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 3]
```

Extract points.

```
pts = Cases[hedron, GraphicsComplex[pts_, other__] :> pts][[1]]
```

Extract indices of polygons

```
polygons = 
 Cases[hedron, GraphicsComplex[pts_, Polygon[other_]] :> other][[1]]
```

Write a function to give the normal to the polygon from its points and indices.

```
normal[pts_, indices_] := 
 With[{a = pts[[indices[[2]]]] - pts[[indices[[1]]]], 
   b = pts[[indices[[3]]]] - pts[[indices[[2]]]]},
  Simplify[Normalize[Cross[a, b]]]
  ]
```

Compute the normals for each facet (I made this numerical, otherwise the expressions become very long)

```
normals = normal[N@pts, #] & /@ polygons
```

Create a handy set of associations for each polygon

```
polygonAssocs = 
 MapThread[<|"polygon" -> #1, 
    "edges" -> Transpose[{#2, RotateLeft[#2]}], 
    "normal" -> #3 |> &, {Range[Length[polygons]], polygons, normals}]
```

e.g.

```
RandomChoice[polygonAssocs]
```

Make a list of all edges on the polygons, keep only the ordered ones.

```
allEdges = 
 Select[Flatten[polygonAssocs[[All, "edges"]] , 1], OrderedQ]
```

A function to see if a polygon contains an edge, either ordered or not. Arrange the pair so that the first polygon is the one containing the oriented edge.

```
containsEdge[pgonAssoc_, edge : {e1_, e2_}] :=
   With[{polygons = 
    Select[pgonAssoc, MemberQ[#edges, {e1, e2} | {e2, e1}] &]},
  Which[
   MemberQ[polygons[[1, "edges"]], edge], polygons,
   True, Reverse[polygons]
   ]
  ]
```

For each edge, find the neighboring polygons, and compute the dot-product of their normals.

```
edgePolygons =
 MapThread[
  With[
    {edge = #1, polygonPair = containsEdge[polygonAssocs, #2]},
    <|"edge" -> edge, "polygons" -> polygonPair, 
     "dihedral" -> 
      ArcCos[
       First[polygonPair]["normal"] . Last[polygonPair]["normal"]]
     |>] &, {Range[Length[allEdges]], allEdges}]
```

e.g.,

```
RandomChoice[edgePolygons]
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer; I must confess though I'm struggling with understanding it. Could be a version mismatch, but I'm getting an error from MapThread: MapThread::mptd: Object normals at position {2, 3} in MapThread[Association[polygon->#1,edges->Transpose[{#2,RotateLeft[Slot[<<1>>]]}],normal->#3]&, ...  has only 0 of required 1 dimensions

Comment: Oh, I forgot to copy and paste the line that computes the normals. It is now edited.  If you are having difficulty understand bits of the code, don't hesitate to ask. I can add more verbage.

Comment: thank you, @Craig Carter. I'm still digesting all the details, but tested it, runs and works and gives the correct result.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** A more direct approach using `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals `` and `"EdgeFaceConnectivity"` to get a `Dataset` with `"edge"` (edge index) `"faces"` (indices of faces connected to `"edge"`), `"facenormals"` (normal vectors for `"faces"`), and `"dihedral"` (dihedral angle of `"faces"`) as columns:

```
ClearAll[edgeDihedrals]
edgeDihedrals[bmr_] := Module[{fn = Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bmr, 2]}, 
 Dataset @ MapIndexed[Association @ {"edge" -> #2[[1]], "faces" -> #, 
   "facenormals" -> AssociationThread[#, fn[[#]]], 
   "dihedral" -> ArcCos[Dot @@ fn[[#]]]} &] @ bmr["EdgeFaceConnectivity"]]
```

***Examples:***

```
bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @  Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 3];

edgeDihedrals[bdg]
```

[image]

```
edgeDihedrals[bdg][Range[10], {"edge", "faces", "dihedral"}]
```

[image]

```
edgeDihedrals[bdg][{1, 2, 3}, {"edge", "dihedral"}]
```

[image: > <|1 -> 0.251943, 2 -> 0.198251, 3 -> 0.251943|>]

```
HighlightMesh[bdg, 
  {Style[{1, 1}, Thick, Red], 
   ## & @@ Thread[{2, Normal @ edgeDihedrals[bdg][1, "faces"]}], 
   Style[{1, 15}, Thick, Green], 
   ## & @@ Thread[{2, Normal @ edgeDihedrals[bdg][15, "faces"]}]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals"]
```

[image]

```
edgeDihedrals @ BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @ PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron"]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

First, use [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.html) to get a [`BoundaryMeshRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion.html) object:

```
bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @  Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 3];
```

We can identify faces connected thru an edge using the properties `"FaceVertexConnectivity"` and `"FaceFaceConnectivity"`. Then, we can use the function `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals `` to get normals for each pair of neighboring faces and use  `Dot` + `ArcCos` to get the dihedral angles.

```
ClearAll[neighboringFaces, dihedralAngle]
neighboringFaces[bmr_] := Module[{faces = bmr["FaceVertexConnectivity"]}, 
   Association @ MapIndexed[Function[{x, ind}, ind[[1]] -> 
     DeleteCases[x, _?(Length[Intersection[faces[[ind[[1]]]], faces[[#]]]] != 2 &)]], 
    bmr["FaceFaceConnectivity"]]];


dihedralAngle[bmr_][i_, j_] /; MemberQ[neighboringFaces[bmr][i], j] :=
    ArcCos[Dot @@ Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[bmr, {{2, i}, {2, j}}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
neighboringFaces[bdg][1]
```

> ```
>  {7, 10, 37}
> ```

```
neighboringFaces[bdg][15]
```

> ```
>  {3, 18, 100}
> ```

```
HighlightMesh[bdg, {Style[{2, 1}, Red], ## & @@ Thread[{2, neighboringFaces[bdg][1]}], 
  Style[{2, 15}, Green], ## & @@ Thread[{2, neighboringFaces[bdg][15]}]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals"]
```

[image]

```
{1, #} -> dihedralAngle[bdg][1, #] & /@ neighboringFaces[bdg][1]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 7} -> 0.198251, {1, 10} -> 0.251943, {1, 37} -> 0.251943}
> ```

```
{15, #} -> dihedralAngle[bdg][15, #] & /@ neighboringFaces[bdg][15]
```

> ```
>  {{15, 3} -> 0.251943, {15, 18} -> 0.198251, {15, 100} -> 0.251943}
> ```

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

Comment: thank you, it works!